# NTL: Solve the closest vector problem for non-square matrix using LLL/Nearest Plane Algorithm

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, lenstra-lenstra-lovasz

Assume I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$, $m > n$, which forms a basis of a lattice. Given a vector target vector $t = Ax + e$, $t,e \in \mathbb{Z}^m$,$x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, I want to find the (approximate) closest vector in the lattice $\mathcal{L}(A)$ to $t$.

I wanted to use Babai's nearest plane algorithm, in particular the NTL implementation `NTL::NearVector` to solve this problem (approximately) using LLL. However, it seems to me that in the literature and definitely in the software package, Babai's nearest plane algorithm requires a full-rank lattice?

What other techniques/embeddings can I use to solve the closest vector problem on an lattice with higher dimension than rank? Could I just extend the matrix with zero-vector columns?

Comment: In the $\ell_2$ norm, it should suffice to project your vector onto the (real) span of your lattice (which is a rank $n$ subspace), then orthogonally rotate this subspace to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}^{m-n}$. I don't know how to do this in NTL in though, so will only leave the comment.

Answer (score 1):

no Babai's nearest plan  algorithm  doesn't necessary need a full rank lattice
look at this paper [here](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/cvp.pdf).