# Do you know any library for implementing lattice-based schemes?

Tags: lattice-crypto, implementation, sis

Good afternoon! I'm trying to write a code for a lattice based scheme (based on the SIS problem).
I'm looking for a library that may help me in this task without taking care of the implementation of the trapdoor generation's algorithm. Moreover, I'm searching for a method  helpful to set the SIS parameters according to a security parameters in bits.

I'd like something written in C/C++ or Rust but I can take into account other languages.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/256128/91764)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/95339/35925)

Answer (score 0):

Micrososft has [one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/lattice-cryptography-library/) in C if it works for you.

Comment: I had already seen it but unfortunately it implements Peikert's key exchange based on ring-lwe.